# Using MATLAB app designer and writecell in a for-loop. Misses getting the value of the first row/item in the for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have this .mlapp from App Designer, and I'm using it to loop through some audiofiles and then record what the listener heard. The listener types what they hear in the sentence into an edit text input (app.response), and then presses "Enter" to record the answer and advance to the next stimulus. When I look at the excel file at the end, it shows the recorded response, but it's all offset by 1 row and the last response is never recorded. It's like somehow the waitfor isn't working right, and it's saving the response before it collects the information from the edit text.
I feel like this should be really straighforward, but it's taken me hours now to figure out - so I've come to the community. What am I missing? I feel like it's something to do with the "waitfor" and setting the current character, while changing the current character by typing out a response? I can't get it right though.

```
function BeginButtonPushed(app, event)
            %set default character on keyboard to 0 (so we can advance by
            %pressing Enter later)
            app.UIFigure.CurrentCharacter = char(0);
            
            %access stimuli
            task = 'Type_babble_1'; %Set task name
            stim_dir=[cd '\stimuli']; %set directory for stimuli 
            FileList = dir(fullfile(stim_dir,'*.wav')); %create list of stimuli
                            
            %loop that controls stimulus playback
            for i=1:length(FileList)
                app.Counter.Value = length(FileList)+1-i; %adding a number for the counter
              
                %load the signal
                signalpath = [stim_dir '\' FileList(play_order(i)).name];
                [fnames,fs]=audioread(signalpath);
              
                %present stimulus
                duration = length(fnames)/fs;
                sound(fnames,fs);
                pause(duration)

                %wait to collect response
                app.UIFigure.CurrentCharacter = char(0);
                waitfor(app.UIFigure,'CurrentCharacter', char(13)) 
                app.UIFigure.CurrentCharacter = char(0);

                %collect trial information and write it to the file.
                sentence_code=FileList(play_order(i)).name;
                output = [cellstr(app.ID.Value) cellstr(task) cellstr(sentence_code) cellstr(app.response.Value)];
                  **%This app.response.Value isn't being recorded on the first loop ^^^^^^^^^^^!**
                disp(output)
                writecell(output,[app.ID.Value '-' task '-data.xlsx'],"Sheet",1,'WriteMode','append');
            end
            fclose('all');
            msgbox('You''re done!')
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, have you considered using flip() on your directory list line? It should order things such that you don't need to subtract i from your counter.Value, and can just set counter.Value to i.
When you run the app, does the output for the first task display correctly in the command window?

Have you tried adding a submit button rather than relying on catching an "enter" key? It might help debug the problem, and once it is fixed you can remove it for the flow of the responses.

Have you tried adding any break points? For example at the point of writing the file. You could advance past that step and check the file to see what and where data is being written, and check to see where an overwrite or non-write is happening.

Without being able to run this myself, those are my first thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I found the issue with some help from MATLAB community. The issue (for future reference) was that the edit field didn't update with the value until focus was lost from the edit text - so it wasn't triggering an update of the text inside the edit field until after enter was pressed. The solution was to rearrange the code and put the logic for storing information into a "ValueChanged" function for the edit element - which is working nicely now.